# Request for use webcam from QWebEngineView

Tags: c++, qt, webcam, qwebengineview

From html5 I can access my local webcam using "getUserMedia" method. Then I test simple example on chrome browser I see dialog with request for access to webcam. But when I load the page in QWebEngineView - the are no dialogs and no video. How to catch this request programmatically and give access or may be exists some flag to access webcam without requests? I use QWebEngineView - widget, not qml.

Comment: What is your platform?

Comment: amd64, desktop, Ubuntu

Comment: On windows same issue) I think cef generate event (get permition from user to access camera), but QWebEngineView (it just a wrapper of cef) not process it.